ReplayKit capture with audio playing from WKWebView
I'm attempting to use ReplayKit to record my app, Its a music production app where I use the WebAudio API to play and synchronize playback and have some animations and things.
ReplayKit appears to capture audio fine in a regular swift app where I am playing audio with AVFoundation, however, when It doesn't capture audio playing from my WKWebView.
I'm having trouble finding any official documentation (or even unofficial for that matter) stating that it does not support audio capture from a WebView. I do not want to record from Microphone, only app audio.
Here is a snippet of my WebView configuration:
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
    configuration.userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: messageHandlerName)

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    return webView
}

Here is where I configure the audio session in .onAppear.
func configureAudioSession() {
    do {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay, .allowBluetooth])
        try session.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        print("Audio session configured successfully for playback and recording.")
    } catch {
        print("Failed to configure audio session:", error)
    }
}

And from my contentView:
var body: some View {
    WebView(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.0.106:3000")!, messageHandlerName: "triggerRecording") { shouldStart in
        print("messageHander", shouldStart)
        if shouldStart {
            recordingManager.startRecording()
        } else {
            recordingManager.stopRecording()
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}

starting, stopping, and previewing the recording is all working fine. It's just that audio is not being captured.
